# QTP filling ajax field

Tags: javascript, ajax, vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

I'm testing web based application with QTP 9. Everything works well but there are some wicket ajax fields which I can't fill.

My scricpt is based on many functions in for cycle.

```
For i=1 to 2
  fill_A()
  fill_B()
Next
```

And than functions.

On a page http://relevantcodes.com/qtp-synchronization-for-ajax-applications/ I found possible sotuion but it also doesn't work. I need to fill WebEdit fields with numbers - they are filled, but numbers are invisible. When I click to a button it disappeared absolutely.

Final code looks like below:

```
    For i=1 to 2
      fill_A()
      fill_B()
    Next

Function ElementSync(ByVal oWebElement)
    If oWebElement.Exist(5) Then
        oWebElement.GetTOProperty("parent").Sync

        Dim desc, ix

        Set desc = Description.Create
        desc("micclass").Value = "WebElement"

        Do
            If oWebElement.GetROProperty("x") > 0 Then
                Reporter.ReportEvent micDone, "Element=>Sync", "Sync complete"
                Exit Do
            End If

            Wait(1)
            ix = ix + 1
        Loop Until ix = 10
    End If
End Function

RegisterUserFunc "WebElement", "Sync", "ElementSync"
RegisterUserFunc "Link", "Sync", "ElementSync"
RegisterUserFunc "WebEdit", "Sync", "ElementSync"

    Function fill_A()
    ...
    EndFunction

    Function fill_B()
    Browser("AAA").WebEdit("BBB").Sync()
    Browser("AAA").WebEdit("BBB").Set("123")
    .....
    EndFunction
```

I'm not expert with special QTP functions, neither web developing so if I wrote something incorrectly, excuse me please :-)

Comment: Thanks Blast for the comment but I don't see what is wrong. Yes - it's copy, paste but it's whole exameple which should work. And yes - I don't understand at all - as I said - it's just example. I think, instead your comment, much better would be to help me to find some way which help me... My script works - I just need to know how to fill AJAX fields.

Comment: That means it does not work. What does not work? Create an example that shows just that. Please.

Comment: I have updated code. If you need other informations (corrections :-) ) just let me know.

Comment: Its not wrong. It is not an sscce. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions. 
The first thing I would (need to!) do when designing a useful answer for this question would have to be: Create an SSCCE. But that´s your job. That´s why I don´t want to answer your question, and that´s unfortunate, isn´t it?

Comment: In other words: Try to simplify as much as possible. F.e., it is not required to registerUserFunc the function. It probably fails, too, if it isnt. Right? So remove all what is there just because it is registered as a method. And so on. The result will be close to an SSCCE, and you probably will see where the problem is. (Or we have an efficient chance to see that, for that matter.) This of course required you to analyze and understand the code you ask about. This is by intention! SO is not a fix-the-code-I´ve-inherited-site. It is a help-me-understand-and-fix-the-problem-in-my-code-site.